# Using next in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iterator

I am looping through an array using foreach.

In a particular situation I need to know the value of the next element before iteration comes to that(like a prediction) element. For that I am planning to use the function [next()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php).

In documentation I just noticed that next() advances the internal array pointer forward.

> next() behaves like current(), with one difference. It advances the
>   internal array pointer one place forward before returning the element
>   value. That means it returns the next array value and advances the
>   internal array pointer by one.

If so will it affect my foreach loop?

Comment: @Jonas while you are editing all of these tags are you considering the possibility of closing duplicates? I think I've seen some dupe closure candidates in your page stirring wake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will not affect your loop
if you use it in this way

```
<?php

$lists = range('a', 'f');

foreach($lists as &$value) {
   $next = current($lists);
   echo 'value: ' . $value . "\n" . 'next: ' . $next . "\n\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> value: a
>   next: b
>
> value: b
>   next: c
>
> value: c
>   next: d
>
> value: d
>   next: e
>
> value: e
>   next: f
>
> value: f
>   next:

Comment: Awesome find. I hope it is stable and forward_compatible. And yes it can be useful. :-)

Comment: Should the line `$next = current($lists);` be `$next = next($lists);`?

Comment: No it's not, you can run this code to your local php environment and try

Comment: @e-motiv **This is not stable and forward-compatible.** It isn't even *backward*-compatible. As tested with http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ this always states "a" as being next in PHP 5.0.4 to 5.1.6. Then from 5.2.16 to 5.6.29 its "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" (so your output) and from 7.0.1 onwards it stays "a". As pointed out in http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/13bjdgjhcz/foreach-and-current#20131118q6fneqrepzxtdk562h7p2wkdmm `foreach` and `current` have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 3):

`next()` *doesn't* affect `foreach()`, period.

In PHP 7.2 at least,

```php
$values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

foreach ($values as $value) {
  next($values);
  $two_ahead = next($values);
  echo("Two ahead: $two_ahead\n");
  echo("Current value: $value\n");
}
```

Produces:

```
Two ahead: c
Current value: a
Two ahead: e
Current value: b
Two ahead: 
Current value: c
Two ahead: 
Current value: d
Two ahead: 
Current value: e
```

Also note that the foreach loop does not affect the position of next, either.  They're independent.

If you have an array with sequential numeric keys (the default), then [ops' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17962864/1028376) is best for what you're trying to do.  I merely answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$a=$array();
foreach($a as $key=>$var)
{
   if(isset($a[$key+1]))
      echo $a[$key+1];//next element
}
```

Comment: This assumes integer indexed array with contiguous keys, which of course arrays in PHP need not be either.  If you wish to safely use this method with unknown arrays or non-integer keys then iterate the result of `array_values($a)`.